# NGINX Rewrite Rules For PHP Pagination

Tags: nginx, pagination

My current URL for pagination looks as follows:

http://localhost:8000/index.php?slug=the-category-name&type=category&page=1

My desired URL should be:

https://mywebsite.com/category/the-category-name/page/1/

If I just want to see the category without pagination I use this rewrite rule:

```
location /category/ {
            rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
            rewrite  ^/category/(.*)/$ /index.php?slug=$1&type=category 
            last;
    }
```

This is how I get the URL:

https://mywebsite.com/category/the-category-name/

What do I need to change in (append into) this config in order to be able to create the pagination like:

- https://mywebsite.com/category/the-category-name/page/1/
- https://mywebsite.com/category/the-category-name/page/2/
- https://mywebsite.com/category/the-category-name/page/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rewrite` statements are evaluated in order and stops when a statement containing a *flag* matches the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

You should place the more specific *regular expression* before the less specific ones.

For example:

```
location /category/ {
    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    rewrite  ^/category/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ /index.php?slug=$1&type=category&page=$2 last;
    rewrite  ^/category/(.*)/$ /index.php?slug=$1&type=category last;
}
```

To make the *regular expressions* more specific, you could use `([^/]+)` to capture the slug and `(\d+)` to capture the page number.

Comment: I've been trying exactly the same string, but it didn't work for me. However, I've just copied and pasted the your one, and it work. Now I'm trying to find the difference. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show me now how to get rid of /category/page/0/ ? Do I need to use any rewrite rule, or it's better do on the PHP side?

Comment: How should it respond to `/category/page/0/`? Currently, it will match your regex and create a `slug=page/0`. If you want to avoid that, change the captures as suggested in my answer.